# How to change the font size of an NSTextView automatically so that the longest paragraph is always not broken?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

How can I change the font size of an NSTextView automatically so that the longest paragraph is always not broken? The NSTextView is resizable, so the size of the font should always change to the maximal possible size in which the text is not broken.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to change the font size, I don't know of a better way than to call `-[NSAttributedString size]` with various font sizes set on it.

If you don't actually care about the font size in the `NSTextStorage`, but just about how it appears on screen, you might be able to set the text view to not wrap and then change the bounds of its superview to effectively "zoom" the text view so its full width is always on screen.